# Is quantum field operator $\psi$ same as quantum field $\psi$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators

So in QFT, quantum field operator $\psi$ is there. $\psi$ seems to take the role of wavefunction in QM, which now acts upon vacuum state. Then, in lagrangian of various quantum field theories, $\psi$ appears, but now it is called quantum field. So is quantum field operator no different from quantum field here? If it is not different, then how can $\psi$ can have scalar $|\psi|$ in any assumption as it only operates upon vacuum state? Assuming that vacuum state is represented by some $n \times 1$ vector (let us forget about infinite-dimension for now), operator should be of the form $n \times n$.

Comment: They are not the same: $\hat\psi(x)$ in QFT is an operator.

Comment: Then what exactly is quantum field?

Comment: And why is quantum field operator often $\psi$ which seems to suggest it's field..? example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_quantization#Quantum_field_operators

Comment: I do not why they omit the hat. So $\hat\psi(x)\propto\sum_k e^{ikr}\hat a_k.$ The states of  $\hat\psi(x)$ are, for instance $|v\rangle=\hat a_{k=0}|0\rangle,$ which represent a particle with null momentum. As exercise, compute $\hat\psi(x)|v\rangle.$

Comment: That clears my confusion a bit.... (because in many text, hat is omitted, not just wikipedia..)

Comment: David Tong in his QFT lectures he says something along the lines of: "We will not be using the hat notation to represent operators in this course. It is so undergraduate."

Answer (score 13):

**The quantum field has nothing to do with the wavefunction.**

This is a peculiar confusion that seems to arise quite often.

**The wavefunction** $\psi(x)$ is a way of representing a quantum state $\lvert \psi \rangle$ in a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_{\mathrm{QM}}$ that is equipped with a position basis $\{\lvert x \rangle \rvert x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ by setting $\psi(x) = \langle x \vert \psi \rangle $. It encodes the *quantum state* of a (mostly one-particle) system.

**The quantum field** $\psi(x)$ is an *operator-valued distribution*, i.e. to every spacetime-point $x$, it associates an operator $\psi(x)$ acting upon the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_{\mathrm{QFT}}$ of the quantum field theory. For free theories, it has a *mode expansion* into creation and annhiliation operators of one-particle states with definite momenta. The quantum field *creates* the quantum states, it does not represent them.

As Emilio Pisanty points out, one might restrict to a special case: In a free (scalar) theory, the field $\psi^\dagger(x)$ is really the Fourier transform of the creation/annihilation operators of definite momenta, and thus, when applied to the vacuum state $\lvert \Omega \rangle$, creates a particle of definite position, that is to say, the QM space of states (at time $t = 0$) is the subspace spanned by $\{ \psi^\dagger(0,\vec x)\lvert \Omega \rangle \vert \vec x \in \mathbb{R}^3\}$ and one has the identification $\lvert \vec x \rangle = \psi^\dagger(0,\vec x)\lvert \Omega \rangle$, so the wavefunction of a state $\lvert \phi \rangle$ would be $\phi(\vec x) = \langle \vec x \vert \phi \rangle = \langle \Omega \vert \psi(0,\vec x) \vert \phi \rangle $, i.e. the QM wavefunction is a range of expectation values of the quantum field.

(Note that this is not a Lorentz invariant way of writing anything here.)

Comment: and you might also add that the two are indeed related. The action of the QFT operator $\hat\psi^\dagger(x)$ on the vacuum $|\emptyset⟩$ produces the same position eigenstates $|x⟩=\hat\psi^\dagger(x)|\emptyset⟩$ as in standard QM. The QM Hilbert space is just the one-particle subspace of the QFT Hilbert space; within this subspace, a QM quantum state $|φ⟩$ with wavefunction $φ(x)$ can be expressed as the action of $\hat\psi^\dagger(x)$ on the vacuum at all positions $x$, with an amplitude given by the wavefunction: $$|φ⟩=\int \text dx|x⟩⟨x|φ⟩=\int\hat\psi^\dagger(x)|\emptyset⟩φ(x)\text dx.$$

Comment: The last comment in parentheses is fundamental! Indeed, more or less everything written starting from "As Emilio Pisanty points out..." is false when dealing  with Lorentz invariant scalar fields. It is true when referring to a scalar theory invariant under Galileo group. The position representation for Lorentz invariant fields is quite subtle and it is studied in the so-called Newton-Wigner theory.

Comment: Is there any state in QFT other than vacuum state $\lvert \Omega \rangle$ like in QM where there are many  quantum states  $\lvert \psi_n \rangle$? Maybe there is not as we are in Heisenberg picture? But what happens to $\lvert \Omega \rangle$ when we are in interaction picture?